# On or upon + gerund

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

Which preposition are we supposed to use - on or upon.

i.e. "On/upon closing the door, set the alarm on."

Answer (score 4):

[Google NGrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=on%20hearing,upon%20hearing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) states that on+gerund is still used more often than upon+gerund (tried with `hearing` below, `opening` and `closing` - the diagrams were a bit different, but the overall result was the same).

[image]